# Hide an image when scroll near bottom

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with my web. I add an image in the right of my content and I set it's style with ***position:fixed***, but when I scroll down to my web's footer, this image is pressed by my web's footer.
So how can I do to hide this image when this is near my web's footer or this image stack up my web's footer?
Thanks for your help!!

Comment: please provide some code or a working jsfidle...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hide the element when `$(document).height()-$(window).scrollTop()` less than a particular value

**Demo:-**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#scrolldown").show('slow');

    $(window).scroll(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //console.log($(document).height()+'-'+$(window).scrollTop());
        if ($(document).height()-$(window).scrollTop() < 500) {
            $("#scrolldown").hide('slow');
        }
        else {
            $("#scrolldown").show('slow');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
#pagewrap{
  height:1000px;
}
#scrolldown {
    position: fixed;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    background: red;
    bottom: 30px;
    right: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pagewrap">
 <h1>Demo</h1>
 <h2><a href="http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/animated-scroll-to-top">test</a></h2>
<div id="scrolldown">
  i ll hide @ bottom
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using: Position: relative; left: 0px; right: 0px; adjust to fit

Comment: This doesn't really answer the OPs question. Read it a bit more carefully and adjust your answer please.